# Reuse FormGroup in multiple pages Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, forms, ionic-framework, ionic4

Im new to Ionic, and I would like to learn how to create reusable components in my project.

So far, I created a component for a reusable input Form as follows:

**input-form.component.html:**

```
<ion-item>
 <form [formGroup]="form">
 <ion-label>{{labelText}}</ion-label>
 <ion-input [formControl]= "control" [id]= "fieldId" class="form-control"></ion-input>
</form>
```

**input-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup }                from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-input-form',
    templateUrl: './input-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./input-form.component.scss'],
    })
   export class InputFormComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() public form: FormGroup;
   @Input() public control: any;
   @Input() public fieldId: any;
   constructor() {
   }

   ngOnInit() {}
  }
```

I am using this template like this:

**Home.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-toolbar>
  <ion-title>welcomeBack</ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
 <form [formGroup]= "customForm">
 <app-input-form [fieldId]="'userName'" [control]="customForm.get('userName')" ></app-input-form>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

**Home.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-welcome-back',
 templateUrl: './welcome-back.page.html',
 styleUrls: ['./welcome-back.page.scss'],
   })
   
export class WelcomeBackPage implements OnInit {
     public customForm: FormGroup;
  
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,) {
    this.customForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userName : 'test'
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
   }
 }
```

I also imported the modules in **app.module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

and added them in the NgModule imports

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
```

but I still get this error when running the app:

```
core.js:6241 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]
Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [ControlContainer]
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It should be good to make a component using static forms. Not everything should be reusable if is not going to be used in more than 2 times. Ex: <app-login-form> and <app-register-form>

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add code below to **Home.module.ts**

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [

    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

  ],
  declarations: []
})
```